# How to force composer to use zip instead of git clone?

Tags: php, git, clone

Wen I use [composer](http://getcomposer.org) to update/install a new project it starts cloning a lot of git repositories. If you have a lot of dependencies, this takes ages. After all I just need the latest version of all the libraries. I'm not going to change anything.

Is there a way to tell composer to download the requested version without cloning? Just fetching the zip version from github would be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoding to https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/840 this is not possible.

> I think we need to add an option for this at some
>   point. What @stof said is not true. The thing is that with dev
>   packages, the chance of updating them on update is much higher than if
>   you just follow tags, and updates are much cheaper once you have a git
>   clone than redownloading the full thing every time. It's a trade-off.
>   But we should probably add a --prefer-dist flag.